Can the standard model $M$ of arithmetic be described as that for which any $m\in M$ is of the form $s(\dots s(0)\cdots )^M$?
Can the standard model $M$ of arithmetic be defined (up to isomorphism) as that for which any element $m$ of $M$ is the semantic meaning of
$$s(\cdots s(0)\cdots )$$
for a finite number of applications of $s$?

This is a great question, but unfortunately the answer is very subtle and difficult. Intuitively speaking, this is what the standard model of arithmetic is. On the other hand, if you are working in a foundational theory like ZFC, there is no way of expressing the dots in your formula in the language of set theory.

So, the definition of $\omega$ in ZFC is quite different: for example, you could define it as the set of ordinals $x$ such that for all $y\in x$, either $y=0$ or there is a $z\in y$ such that $s(z)=y$. (You need the axiom of infinity to show that $\omega$ is a set.) Whether this definition really agrees with what we think of the "Platonic" natural numbers as being is a very difficult question to answer.

@Joe I don't agree. In ZFC there is a perfectly good way of expressing this: it means that $M$ is the smallest subset of $M$ containing $0$ and closed under $s$. Then it is a theorem in ZFC that $M$ is isomorphic to $\omega$.

@ZhenLin: I don't think that definition exactly captures what we mean when we say that the natural numbers are those that can be reached by a finite number of applications of the successor function. In my mind, there is a difference between the metatheoretical notion of "finite" (i.e. what we think of "finite" as meaning before we learn about set theory or logic), and how "finite" is defined internally in the language of ZFC. If we take a Platonist view of set theory for simplicity [...]

[...] where the axioms of ZFC are seen as describing the cumulative hierarchy $V$, then I'm willing to agree that $\omega\in V$ is the set of actual natural numbers ${0,1,2,3,\dots}$, as given by the dots in the question. But within $V$ we can find (set) models $N$ of ZFC such that $\omega^N$ is not isomorphic to $\omega$. This is because ${0^N,1^N,2^N,\dots}$ is actually not an element of the model $N$, which allows $\omega^N$ to be longer than it really should be. To me, this suggests that ZFC cannot really pin down exactly what we mean by the natural numbers.

Yes. Obviously I mean to take ZFC as the metatheory.

First, notice that "finite number of applications of $s$" presupposes a notion of finite number, and moreover one that supports a notion of iteration.
Although there are several possible definitions of "finite set", it is unclear to me how one can iterate the application of an operator $X$-many times for, say, a Dedekind-finite set $X$.
Therefore let me assume by "finite number" you really do mean a natural number in the usual sense.
It is then almost a tautology that a model of arithmetic in which every element is obtained as a finite number of applications of $s$ to (the interpretation of) $0$ is isomorphic to the standard natural numbers: after all, it is an axiom that $s$ is injective, and the hypothesis is precisely that the set
$$\{ 0, s (0), s (s (0)), s (s (s (0))), \ldots \}$$
is the set of elements of the model, so the map $n \mapsto s^n (0)$ is the desired isomorphism.
To formalise the argument above, one must first pick a formalism.
Suppose we work in ZFC (but much less will suffice; for example, Mac Lane set theory).
Then the standard natural numbers are defined to be the smallest set $\omega$ such that $\emptyset \in \omega$ and if $n \in \omega$ then $n \cup \{ n \} \in \omega$.
It is a theorem of ZFC (or, indeed, Mac Lane set theory) that we may define functions on $\omega$ by simple recursion.
Indeed, suppose we have a set $X$, $x_0 \in X$, and $s : X \to X$.
Define $F \subseteq \omega \times X$ to be the set of all $\langle n, x \rangle$ such that there exists $F' \subseteq \omega \times X$ with all of the following properties:

$\langle n, x \rangle \in F'$
For all $x' \in X$, if $\langle \emptyset, x' \rangle \in F'$, then $x' = x_0$.
For all $\langle n', x' \rangle \in F'$ and all $x'' \in X$, if $\langle n' \cup \{ n' \}, x'' \rangle \in F'$, then $x'' = s (x')$.

Now consider $D = \{ n \in \omega : \exists (x \in X) (\langle n, x \rangle \in F \}$.
It is clear, I hope, that $\langle \emptyset, x_0 \rangle \in F$.
It should also be clear that if $\langle n, x \rangle \in F$ then $\langle n \cup \{ n \}, s (x) \rangle \in F$.
Therefore, $\emptyset \in D$ and if $n \in D$ then $n \cup \{ n \} \in D$.
But then $D = \omega$, so $F$ is the graph of a total function $\omega \to X$.
Now apply this to the purported standard model of arithmetic.
